# How do we calculate the accuracy of a multi-class classifier using neural network

Tags: python, neural-network, multiclass-classification

When the outputs (prediction) are the probabilities coming from a Softmax function, and the training target is one-hot type, how do we compare those two different kinds of data to calculate the accuracy?

(the number of training data classified correctly) / (the number of the total training data) *100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, we assign the class label with highest probability in the output of the soft max function as the label.

Answer (score 0):

preds is list of probability of the label

```
 index=np.argmax(preds)
```

it will return index of that label from which class it belong